# Whats the most functional solution to farmers "print animals"?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way of printing the animals, while ensuring that future animals can be listed without changing the code much? My tryout is very amature...

```
var animals = ["Cows", "Chickens", "Pigs", "Horses"];

var printFarm = function(a, b, c, d){

console.log("You have " + a + " " + animals[0]);
console.log("You have " + b + " " + animals[1]);
console.log("You have " + c + " " + animals[2]);
console.log("You have " + d + " " + animals[3]);

};

printFarm(3, 6, 17, 54);
```

Comment: Why are there numbers for the parameters? Does each number represent an animal? Did you run this code and see what the error is on devtools? 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Ok sorry next time will definitely create a demo thnx for noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass in an integer array to the function, and then do a loop with whatever the minimum number of items in either your animals array or your integer array is?

```
 var animals = ["Cows", "Chickens", "Pigs", "Horses"];

 var printFarm = function(animalCounts) {

      var index = Math.min(animals.length, animalCounts.length);

      for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
           console.log("You have " + animalCounts[i] + " " + animals[i];
      }
 }

 printFarm([1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what Math.min does in this example? It is the only thing that i cant get. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just to catch errors, so the index would never be out of range. Ex. if you added an animal but forgot to add a count in the function parameters, you wouldn't get an error if you are using the minimum value of the two lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways of doing it...

```
var animals = ["Cows", "Chickens", "Pigs", "Horses"];

function printFarm(arrAnimals) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrAnimals.length; i++) {
        var animalGroup = arrAnimals[i];
        var amount = printFarm.arguments[i + 1];
        if (amount) {
            console.log('You have ' + amount + ' ' + animalGroup + '.');
        } else {
            console.log('No amount was found for ' + animalGroup + '.');
        }
    }
}

printFarm(animals, 3, 6, 17, 54);
```

So, all you need to do is to change your array to include a new animal and then simply append the amount to the end of the printFarm function call, like I've done above. Alternatively, you could just pass an array of animal counts to the function in addition to the animal array.

Or pass it an array of animalCount objects that have the name of the animal and the count as part of the object. Like so...

```
var animals = [{ name:'cows', count:3 },
               { name:'chickens', count:6 },
               { name:'pigs', count:17 },
               { name:'horses', count:54 }];

function printFarm(arrAnimals) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrAnimals.length; i++) {
        var animalGroup = arrAnimals[i];
        var name = animalGroup.name;
        var amount = animalGroup.count;
        console.log('You have ' + amount + ' ' + name + '.');
    }
}

printFarm(animals);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to create an Animal class and create an object for each animal required. This is a rough example, but shows the idea.

```
function Animal(type, count) {
  this.type = type;
  this.count = count;

  this.print = function() {
    console.log("You have " + this.count + " " + this.type);
  }
}
```

Probably a better approach is an Animal base class with each new animal type added subclassing it, but this does the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/f9n0en7e/